# How to iterate loop in JavaScript if we have dynamic object names

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some dynamically created locations like S1, T6, U6, U11 etc. I have to iterate it in one for loop in my React component. How I can able to do it ?

Please review attached screen shot. Thanks

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/olm6w.png]

Comment: You can use Object.keys

Answer (score 0):

```
const obj = {
  s1: [],
  T6: [],
  U11: []
}

Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key,arr])=>{
    //key is s1, T6 etc..

    //if want to iterate arr value
    arr.forEach(i=>{
      //value inside array
    })
})
```

OR

```
//if just need value
for(value of Object.values(obj)){
  console.log(value)
}
```

OR

```
//if want key value pair
for(key of Object.keys(obj)){
  console.log(key,obj[key])
}
```

OR

```
for(const [key,value] of Object.entries(obj)){
  console.log(key,value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version of some code I wrote earlier. It's a little over-the-top in answering this question, but a real-world React example might be useful to you.

Here I pass in an object with those "dynamically created locations" as the keys on an object, and arrays as the values. I pass in the object to `Example`, then use `createRows` to insert table rows on render.

In `createRows` we take the object and iterate over it with [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries). The callback for this object method returns both the key and the value in an array, and we can use those to populate the cells of the rows being returned.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">

  // The main function that will loop over the data
  // and create the rows for the table
  function createRows(data) {

    // Iterate over the data and for each object
    // return a new HTML row
    return Object.entries(data).map(([ key, value ], i) => {
      return (
        <tr key={i}>
          <td>{key}</td>
          <td>{value}</td>
        </tr>
      )
    });
  }

  function Example({ input }) {

    // If there's no data in state display nothing...
    if (!Object.keys(input).length) return <div>No data</div>

    // ...otherwise pass the data into the createRows function
    // and return them the row data
    return (
      <table>
        <thead>
          <th>Key</th>
          <th>Value</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {createRows(input)}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )
  };

  const input = {
    S1: [1, 2, 3],
    T6: [4, 5, 6],
    U11: [7, 8, 9]
  };

  // Render it
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Example input={input} />,
    document.getElementById("react")
  );

</script>
<div id="react"></div>
```